# How to show decimal zeroes for a number in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am pulling the following numbers from MS SQL Server:

345
345.6
345.67

How do I pull them so that they look like the following:

345.00
345.60
345.67

What datatype should they be stored as and what is the magic function to pull them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cast function. Since you are pulling out values of a table, you would be using a select and some thing like the following can be used-

```
Select CAST(value AS DECIMAL(5,2)) from table
```

I hope that is what you are looking for.

cheers